# Unable to access individual alignment strings in biopython pairwise align

Tags: python, alignment, sequence, biopython, pairwise

I'm trying to access individual strings in the alignment object which is produced by the pairwise aligner in biopython but not getting anywhere. I'm talking about the already aligned sequences showing gaps, as given by the print(alignment), but trying to get them individually or even slice. The documentation stipulates it's possible but I'm getting errors.

```
from Bio import Align
aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner(mode='global',gap_score=-5)
my_target= 'CAGGTGCAGCTGGTGCAGAGCGGCGCGGAAGTGAAAAAACCGGGCAGCAGCG'
my_query='CAGTGCAGCTGGTGCAGAGCGACGCGGAAGTGAAAAAACCGGGAGCAGCG'
aln= aligner.align(my_target,my_query)
print(aln[0])
```

The result is:

```
CAGGTGCAGCTGGTGCAGAGCGGCGCGGAAGTGAAAAAACCGGGCAGCAGCG
|||-||||||||||||||||||.|||||||||||||||||||||-|||||||
CAG-TGCAGCTGGTGCAGAGCGACGCGGAAGTGAAAAAACCGGG-AGCAGCG
```

Now, I'd like to get the 'query' sequence in the bottom line individually.
I can access the aln[0].query but this seems to be just the naked query seq not as aligned (with gaps).

The documentation stipulates the alignment object should be iterable to slice it but this simply is not working.

What I'm getting is:

```
aln.alignment[1]

File c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Align\__init__.py:1024, in PairwiseAlignment.__getitem__(self, key)
   1022     raise NotImplementedError
   1023 if isinstance(key, int):
-> 1024     raise NotImplementedError
   1025 if isinstance(key, tuple):
   1026     try:

NotImplementedError:
```

The doc:

[image]

I'd appreciate some help, pointers.
Cheers.

Comment: What version of Biopython and python are you using ?

Comment: good point... I have Conda with Python 3.9.12  but running Biopython 1.78. This version got set up by install on conda just a couple of days ago.  Now I can see this is not the latest.

Comment: Using python 3.11 and biopython 1.81, it seems to work but you need to use `aln._alignment[1]`

Comment: updated to 1.81 but no luck on python 3.9.12.  Need to check python 3.8 next - seems to be mentioned in the biopython ref.

Comment: OK, that's actually working. Got 1.81 and python 3.11 and I can see ._alignment property now (but not .alignment). Also discovered I was using VSCode interactive pointed to base while being in other env. After cleaning up I can see what I needed.
Many thanks @ftorre

Comment: So this is getting weird... I can access aln._alignment but only after I use aln[0] anywhere upstream in the code. Otherwise I'm getting 'object has no attribute ._alignment "...
So this is unstable...

Comment: Indeed, variables prefixed with _ generally means that they should only be used by the package, and not the end user (you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)). Looking through the [source code](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/Align/__init__.py), I noticed that the _alignment is actually returned by  \_\_getitem\_\_. You can therefore access the alignment query with: `aln[0][1]` or `aln[1][1]` as there are two alignments in your case. `aln[0][0]`returns the target.

Comment: BIOPYTHON VERSION : 1.80 works fine with just print(aln[0][1]) and  print(aln[0][10), both print(aln[0]) and print(aln[1]) return the entire alignment

Answer (score 3):

Answering own question.
In biopython 1.81 and python 3.11.3  it seems the alignment object is iterable and each iteration is iterable further to access the aligned strings showing the deletions/insertions.
So in the code from the original question I'm doing:

```
aln[0][1]
```

to get:

```
CAG-TGCAGCTGGTGCAGAGCGACGCGGAAGTGAAAAAACCGGG-AGCAGCG
```

or slicing the string:

```
aln[0][1][start:stop]
```

It does not work in python 3.9.12 though ('Not implemented' error when trying aln[0][N]), N being 0 or 1.